# Create multiple empty files using tcsh terminal

Tags: file, tcsh

I would like to create multiple empty files using tcsh, similar to the command:

```
touch {0..999}.txt
```

**no bash installed.**

> %echo $SHELL
>
> %/bin/tcsh

If possible, not using script but a terminal command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a simple script that does it:

file name: `script`

```
\#!/bin/tcsh

set j = 1
while ($j <= 10000)
     touch $j.txt
     @ j++ 
end
```

changed the permissions for the script to +x :

```
chmod +x script
```

and executed :

```
./script
```

Comment: Can you please expalin why you consider this approach better than `alias script "touch 'seq -f %.0f.txt 1 999'"`

Comment: I was looking for any solution. didn't really consider one over the other

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seq`'s formatting option and avoid the loop by passing multiple args to `touch`:

```
touch `seq -f %.0f.txt 1 999`
```